# Table of Latitude and Longitude with Associated Elevation

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, latitude-longitude, elevation, table

I need to create a table that allows me to retrieve the elevation value for a given GPS coordinate pair. Currently, I am just doing this for New Zealand. I'm working in QGIS using a GeoTIFF file, and have already extracted the contours from the raster. This has given me a table of elevation values for the contour id's, but I need a table of lat/long pairs and their elevation values. Is there a way to extract this data from the GeoTIFF as a table?

Comment: Extracting contours from a DEM is a step in the wrong direction if you're looking for Z values on points -- you can easily obtain spot vales with just points and a raster, without the ugly interpolation that would need to occur from contours.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that I may need to make a super huge point layer then...

Comment: I think you'll find that, too, is a step in the wrong direction. You say you have GPS points, why not use them to query the surface directly?

Comment: That is a thought, although I don't know how to query for elevation using the GPS coordinates. It would be nice if there were a way that I could loop through all of the GPS coordinates and create a table in a CSV or something.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand what your GeoTIFF file represents.

If your GeoTIFF file contains elevation values, you can use the ***Drape (set Z value from raster)*** QGIS algorithm to set Z values of the points to the elevation value of the raster at that position.
*Input Layer*: Your point layer; *Raster layer*: the DEM.

Comment: The GeoTIFF does contain elevation values. Thank you very much for your answer, I think that this should be helpful.

I don't have a point layer, though— do I need to create one? I'm guessing that I would need to essentially make one that would have a point per pixel of the raster layer if I did.

Comment: If you have lines and want elevation values for the points / vertices of those lines, you can use the same "algorithm" for that (the algorithm takes both point and line layers as input).